# How to get a php variable back to android app?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

i am new to programming in Android Studio, i am trying to connect my application to MySQL database on a web server, the `echo "login success !!!!! Welcome $user";` is working fine just as i desire, but i want to get a PHP variable like `$user` also back to my android studio development so that i can use it to make sessions in the application, but i am unable to get the variable
I am getting the echo and i am using it somewhere else like to display the success of login. need help thank you

```
    <?php
    require "pconn.php";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $hash = md5($password);

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM UserLogin WHERE Email='".$username."' and BINARY Password ='".$hash."'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$qry);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $user = $row['Username'] ;
   echo "login success !!!!! Welcome $user";
   echo $user;
   }
   else {
   echo "login not success";
   }


   ?>
```

and my Java Class is:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://xaas.com/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String username = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }



                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `How to get a php variable back to android studio?` Wrong question. I think you want to receive the value of that variable in your client App that runs on an Android device. When your app runs on your device, or of somebody else, it has little to do with Android Studio.

Comment: @greenapps I think you mean it has **absolutely nothing** to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) for displaying anything to the `php` console and `echo` just the part you want to send as a response to the android device.

Or, if you want to send `"login success !!!!! Welcome $user"` string as a response as well. Then simply get value of `$user` at the android side.

The first time you do `echo` that will be sent as the response. If you want to send multiple strings then construct a json, populate it with whatever you want to send and finally echo it. Something like this:

```
$data = [ 'loginMessage' => 'login success !!!!! Welcome $user', 'user' => '$user' ];
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Then get the values back at android side using [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```
JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(result);
String loginMessage = responseJSON.getString("loginMessage");
String userName = responseJSON.getString("user");
```

Comment: i need both echos, first to display a toast of login success and the other to be used further in my application.

Comment: i am now understanding the logic, can you please help me in how to get them back in android side? like how to differentiate between the values? thanks a ton

Comment: @YasarKhalid The PHP script should only return the data. The Android app should then be responsible for creating the message for the Toast. Do not rely on the PHP script to make the message for the Android Toast.

Comment: @AbhishekJain can you please suggest me where to add this JSONObject code in my Javaclass?

Comment: @YasarKhalid Put it after your while loop, this one: `while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)`

Answer (score 2):

Just like all the answers above, you will need to echo your php output as json.
To achieve this, you can try the following code in your php file

```
$result["sessionID"] = $user;
$result["response_message"] = "Log in success!"
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now you have to parse the result of your OutputStream, to do this, you can try the followin code in your android class

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject([your variables that holds the result from output stream]);
String sessionID = jsonobj.getString("sessionID");
String response_message = jsonobj.getString("response_message");
```

Please note that the parameter you passed to jsonobj.getString("**sessionID**") should be the same as the parameter you passed when you declare your variable $response["**sessionID**"] in php file.

I would also suggest you familiarize yourself with JSON syntax.

Answer (score 1):

JSON and XML are both common ways to return data from a web server to a mobile app.

Alternatively, enter the user name and password directly in Android EditTexts and send the data to the PHP script. Just be careful that you use HTTPS not plain HTTP.

Comment: can you please explain one example of getting the `$user` value back in Android Studio please? :)

Comment: @YasarKhalid I suggest you learn about creating JSON objects in PHP. There are already many examples online about how to do this.